# Meteor Deployed Showing Default Nginx Page

Tags: node.js, nginx, meteor, telescope

I successfully deployed my meteor app with similar settings shown in this tutorial:

http://code.krister.ee/hosting-multiple-instances-of-meteor-on-digitalocean/

When I visit the URL, the default nginx shows up. I tried using a different url such as demo.example.com, but nothing loads.

I even tried changing the ports from 3001 to 80 to no ports specified in the `mup.json` file

I checked the nginx/sites-enabled files and there was only `default`, so I created a new one as outlined in the tutorial.

I still can't get my ip or domain to load my app. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

nginx is not pointing to the correct location. The default port for Telescope is `3000`. Have you tried setting the nginx configuration file to look for `http://localhost:3000` instead of on port `3001` like the tutorial suggests?

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection ‘upgrade’;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
```